# jquery or js: replace a link site-wide with another AND change to https

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change every instance of

```
http[s]://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=foo
```

to

```
https://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=bar
```

I think its must be able to be done with `attr.replace` but I can't figure out the notation. How can I do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

EDIT:  it seems everyone so far is either missing the first part (http OR https changes to https) or the second part (foo to bar) :)  Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
$('a[href$="://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=foo"]')
    .attr('href', 'https://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=bar');
```

The [*attribute-ends-with* selector *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) is a native CSS3 selector, so selecting these elements should be quite fast. Of course you could also use a regular expression for the `http[s]` part and, e.g., `.filter`, but that is likely to be slower (also depends on the number of links you have).

In case the URL contains other parameters which should also be part of the new URL, you have to process each link individually:

```
// Using the attribute-contains selector now. This still assumes that 
// `this_page=foo` is the first parameter in the URL
var pattern = /^https?:\/\/www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=foo(&|$)/;
$('a[href*="://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=foo"]')
  .attr('href', function(i, val) {
      return val.replace(pattern, 'https://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=bar$1');
  });
```

If `this_page` can be anywhere in the URL, you can get all links that contain `this_page=foo` and the base URL. This works only if there is no other page value which starts with `foo`:

```
var pattern_page = /([?&])this_page=foo(&|$)/;

$('a[href*="://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?"][href*="this_page=foo"]')
  .attr('href', function(i, val) {
      return val.replace('http:', 'https:')
                .replace(pattern_page, '$1this_page=bar$2');
  });
```

Comment: No problem; original comment deleted (as will this be, shortly) =)

Comment: what if the URL in the content is relative, but _would_ refer to that link once fully qualified?

Comment: @Alnitak: Then only take the relative part, e.g. `a[href$="/test/index.php?this_page=foo"]`. It should be easily adjustable.

Comment: @FelixKling yup, that would work.  I was trying to add some text to my answer about how you should make the match _just_ specific enough to do the job, but not so specific that it'll fail for minor variants but couldn't quite write it the way I wanted to.

Comment: @Alnitak: One problem I could see is in case you have them mixed, absolute and relative URLs, but even in that case, one could use the multiple selector to cover both cases... there are many ways to solve the problem I was just thinking about one that does not involving too much processing for each element.

Comment: @FelixKling that's why I've used `.prop` instead of the actual attribute.  The property is always absolute.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yeah... would be interesting to make a http://jsperf.com/ and compare them...

Comment: Hmm... it didn't... well, it just didn't work :(  I copied and pasted and of course change mydomain to my actual domain... double checked the path exactly... no love :(  no error... just no replacement.

Comment: scratch that... it worked once I put it inside a $(document).ready(function(){});   Yes, I'm proud of myself for figuring that out!

Comment: The "problem" with this solution (its actually a problem with my question!) is that it doesn't allow for any parameters passed with the url (ie. ?this_page=bar&param1=value).

Comment: @user1438619: Does this mean you want to copy existing parameters to the new URL?

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax would be something like:

```
$('a').prop('href', function(index, value) {
    return newValue;
});
```

where the calculation of `newValue` will depend on exactly how you want to transform the URL, i.e. something like:

```
$('a').prop('href', function(index, value) {
    if (value.match(/=foo\??/) {
        value = value.replace(/=foo\??/, '=bar?').replace(/^http:/, 'https:');
    }
    return value;
});
```

I've used `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` because it seems like you want to access the fully qualified URL.  Using the property rather than the attribute will give you that - the attribute won't always include the URL scheme.

Comment: This replaces ALL links from http to https, not just the link in question

Answer (score 0):

replace all instances!!

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == 'http[s]://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=foo') {
        $(this).attr('href', 'https://www.mydomain.com/test/index.php?this_page=foo');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is contained in the `href` attribute of links, try the following:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http:") != -1) {
        $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace("http", "https"));
    }
});
```

There may be more efficient ways, but this should do the trick.

Regards,
Richard

Comment: that doesn't change foo to bar though, does it?

Comment: ah, sorry I didn't notice the difference between foo and bar - I saw that there was one character difference between the first link and the second link (the s) and assumed that was the only difference. Like the asker says, everyone is missing either the http|https bit or the foo|bar bit.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all http references in anchors with https across the entire page.

```
​$.each($('a'), function(i,v){
  var oldULR =  $(v).attr('href');
  var newURL = oldULR.replace('http', 'https');
  $(this).attr('href', newURL);

})​;​
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/bkNLD/

Comment: 1.  don't read/modify/write - use the function based version of `.attr()`.  2. the `.attr()` may not include the URL scheme, but `.prop()` will.  3.  you haven't addressed the foo/bar change.

Comment: The guy said he was new to javascript, so I wrote something he would easily be able to understand and mimic.

Comment: 4. don't use `$.each()` on a jQuery collection, it should be `$('a').each(...)`

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript, you could use:

```
var links = document.links;

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    href = links[i].href;
    if (href.indexOf('https') == -1) {
        links[i].href = href.replace('http', 'https');
        href = links[i].href;
    }
    if (href.split('=')[1] == 'foo'){
        links[i].href = href.replace('foo','bar');
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KvUHs/).

In the above I've worked under the, probably wrong, assumption that the two replacements weren't necessarily mutually-dependent. If they are, then it becomes simpler:

```
var links = document.links;

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    href = links[i].href;
    if (href.indexOf('https') == -1 && href.split('=')[1] == 'foo') {
        links[i].href = href.replace('http', 'https');
        links[i].href = href.replace('foo','bar');
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KvUHs/2/).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this and was as much a noob as I... this is the solution I ended up using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('a[href*="this_page=foo"]').prop('href', function(index, value) {
  return value.replace(/=foo/, '=bar').replace(/^http:/, 'https:');
  });
});
```

it is a combination of Felix Kling's and Alnitak's and my big thanks to both of them.